# SKTexture from NSImage with transparent background

Tags: macos, sprite-kit, transparency, nsimage

I'm trying to create Spritekit textures with a transparent background on the fly by using [SKTexture textureWithImage:(NSImage *)];

The textures are drawn with NSBezierPath drawing methods like so:

```
NSImage *img = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:frame.size];
[img lockFocus];

NSBezierPath *path = ...
[path stroke]; // etc...

[img unlockFocus];

SKTexture *tex =  [SKTexture textureWithImage:img];
SKSpriteNode *node = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:tex];
[self.scene addChild:node];
```

What I want is the bezier paths to be drawn against a transparent background. My problem is that I can't figure out how to make the image background transparent. It is white by default. It seems that you have to tell NSImage to composite additively against something, but I don't understand against what to composite.

There is this:

```
[img drawInRect:frame fromRect:frame operation:NSCompositeSourceOver fraction:.5 respectFlipped:YES hints:nil];
```

But I'm not sure where/how to use it because it doesn't seem to do anything on its own.

Basically I need to figure out how to create an NSImage which effectively is the same as if you would load a transparent PNG from disk.

thanks!